# Is this how I write a bridge in laravel?

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5, mockery, service-provider

I am writing a bridge in laravel between a library and laravel it's self and I thought the best way was to write a service provider package. It would be a package with one class that looks like:

```
<?php

namespace Eve\Service\Provider;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use EveOnline\Items\Details;

class EveMarketProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    protected $defer = true;

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(Details::class, function ($app) {
            return new Details();
        });

        ... // More classes.
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return [
            Details::class,
            ... // More classes.
        ];
    }
}
```

The goal is the be able to do (in the Laravel app) `Details::functionName`. Currently when you bring in the library I am building the bridge for, I already have providers and facades for each of the components. So you register those appropriately.

I have been informed that coupling my library with Laravel like that so tightly is not a good idea. So my questions are simple:

- Is this the correct way to write a bridge between a library and laravel? Where the class(es), theres more then one,  are registered this way? And will it work as I **expect** it too?
- How do you test this provider? This Bridge package would need to be mocked and I know how to use Mockery, but how would you write effective tests to make sure this acts as expected?

Comment: This code is great for dependency injection. You'll be able to inject `EveOnline\Item\Details` into a controller method, for example. And you'll get a single instance. However if you also want to do `Details::class` you'll need a Facade as well.

Comment: Ill have to create individual facades as I was able to create one large service provider that registers all the classes. How ever my question remains unanswered: How do I write tests for this? Or do I? Do I just point them to the tests for the actual library it's self?